# Why is the object that I created staying at null?

Tags: java, class, object

I've written a simulation in Java, but hit some problems when running. The custom classes I created to simulate aspects of the model seem to never get initialized. For example,

```
public class Queue {
public static int front = -1;
public static int length = 0;
public static int capacity = 0;
public static int roadqueue[];
public static int position[];
public static boolean full = false;

public static void push(int pushValue) {
```

and then the functions that can be run from the class.

In my main project, I declare the class as follows:

```
public class myProject {

public static Queue queue[] = new Queue[33];
```

and then in the main function, I call a function first thing that is supposed to initialize values in this class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
initQueue();
```

with

```
 public static void initQueue() {
queue[0].length = 6000;
queue[14].length = 6000;
queue[1].length = 20;
queue[13].length = 20;
queue[3].length = 10;
queue[11].length = 10;
queue[4].length = 360;
queue[12].length = 360;
queue[5].length = 260;
queue[10].length = 260;
queue[6].length = 20;
queue[9].length = 400;
queue[15].length = 460;
queue[22].length = 460;
queue[16].length = 260;
queue[21].length = 260;
queue[17].length = 100;
queue[26].length = 100;
queue[18].length = 160;
queue[20].length = 140;
queue[23].length = 240;
queue[25].length = 140;
queue[27].length = 80;
queue[32].length = 80;
queue[28].length = 480;
queue[31].length = 140;

for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    if (i == 3 || i == 12)
    queue[i].capacity = 40;
    else
    queue[i].capacity = queue[i].length / 10;
    queue[i].position = new int[queue[i].capacity];
    queue[i].roadqueue = new int[queue[i].capacity];
}
}
```

However, when I run the project and insert breakpoints, the for loops start iterating, but Netbeans informs me that, for instance at

```
queue[0].length = 6000;
```

"length references a null object", and in the variable explorer all the values in queue[] remain null throughout the program. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show a *short* but *complete* program that demonstrates the problem. Rather than all the separate snippets, just show a complete program - it only needs to be about 10 lines long...

Comment: you need to create a Queue object in each slot of your array. I.e `queue[0] = new Queue(); queue[0].length = 6000;` etc.

Comment: why are the variables static? this way, each object has the same values. i dont believe this is the right output

Comment: @ZouZou: While that would normally be the case, the `length` variable is actually a `static` variable - which means it shouldn't matter. Admittedly the fact that it's static is broken in itself, but...

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right but I can't see any other explanation to this. Maybe the OP change the fields to non-static fields and forgot to post the actual code...

Comment: @ZouZou: Exactly - that's why I've asked for a short but complete program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
public static Queue queue[] = new Queue[33];
```

...just creates the *array*. You still have to create the *entries* in the array, e.g.:

```
queue[0] = new Queue();
```

This distinction makes particular sense if you think in terms of why you have an array in the first place: Each of the objects in it may have different state. So using an abstract example:

```
// Create a Person array
Person[] people = new Person[3];

// Add Joe, Mohammed, and Maria to it
people[0] = new Person("Joe");
people[1] = new Person("Mohammed");
people[2] = new Person("Maria");
```

(I've used explicit indexes there, but typically you'd loop through and use the loop variable.)

But note the *very* important thing Jon Skeet picked up on in the comments: Your `Queue` class's members are all `static`, so there's only one **one** `length` (for instance) for the entire class. Because of that, and because of a quirk of Java, this line:

```
queue[0].length = 6000;
```

*actually* does this:

```
Queue.length = 6000;
```

You want to make those members instance members (remove the `static` from them), initialize them to relevant values in a constructor, and initialize the entries in the array (the `queue[x] = new Queue();` above).

Comment: Ah, thanks a million. I'll try this, but it sounds like it will work.

Comment: @Martin: See Jon Skeet's comments, your `Queue` class's members are all `static`. It would make more sense to make them instance members and initialize the instances (per the above).

Answer (score 4):

All elements of an array are automatically initialized to their default value (in your case, `null`). You have an array of 33 null `Queue`s.

As others suggested, you need to assign an instance of `Queue` to your elements before using them

```
queue[i] = new Queue();
//now you can use queue[i]
```

LE: Btw, I doubt you want those fields in `Queue` to be `static`. You're creating an array of `Queue`s that all have the same fields. You may want to remove the `static` keyword from those fields (this may include also removing `static` from some of your `Queue` methods).

Comment: @BoristheSpider But the array elements are `null` regardless.

Comment: @user16547: Yes, they're null - but that won't lead to a NullPointerException as they aren't being dereferenced in the code provided. You can try it for yourself.

Comment: @JonSkeet Now I see and it's quite subtle.

Comment: @JonSkeet: OMG, I see it now. Yikes.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Array in Java it allocates the array itself - but everything inside the Array is null. Essentially you create a street with plots for lots of houses but don't build any houses.

You need to go through building houses in each of the plots before you can do anything with the houses.

So loop through the queue, creating your `Queue` objects.

```
for (int i=0;i<queue.length;i++) {
    queue[i] = new Queue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Queue queue[] = new Queue[33];` Your array is an `Queue` type and it is an `Object`. The moment you initialize your array. All element will assign to it's default value, in this case it is `null` since default value of an `Object` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

i think ur missing, taht u only got onr Queue object. U need to have one on every position of the Array.

like

```
queue[1] = new Queue();
```